# Would anyone be able to explain why this code is giving me an Error while trying to make a boxplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm trying to make a boxplot using ggplot2.
i entered some basing code into the console section of R studio

```
ggplot(data = Movies, aes(x = Genre, y = Gross%US))
```

I keep getting an error saying

> Error: unexpected input in "ggplot(data=Movies, aes(x = Genre, y =
> GrossUS(%))"

and I'm not sure why because I'm following a YouTube video and have been following the exact same code as him (obviously changing it to suit my specific data I'm using etc.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try wrapping the column name containing special characters in backticks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to specificy the `geom` function, try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
   
 Movies_filtered <- Movies %>%
           # keep only the genres you specify
           filter(Genre %in% c("action", "adventure", "comedy"))
    
     ggplot(data = Movies_filtered, aes(x = Genre, y = `Gross%US`))+
          geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!   Just tried it there it's actually now working!

Comment: Try again, i just edited the code.  Was just like the guy who comment said, the $ symbol in variable names often creates problems, so you need to put inside a ` `.

Comment: Hi Lucca perfect i got the boxplot showing in the plot section in R Studio. The only thing is though it's showing every single genre on the boxplot (understandably so), would you know how i would go about to adding the original code in order to show only specific genres? (e.g action, adventure, animation, comedy and drama)

Comment: or to filter out the data i do not need etc?

Comment: use filter() function in dplyr package. You can filter by keeping what you want, or excluding what you dont want. I edited the awnser to a way that you keep what you want.

Comment: hey man tried the updated code but i am getting Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  filter(Genre %in% c("action", "adventure", "comedy")
ggplot"

Comment: the genres categories are described all lowe case, exactly how its writed? And your called dplyr and ggplot2 packages before all instructions?

Comment: yeah everything is in low case (the data table also has low case), and yeah i have the library(ggplot2)  and library(dplyr) aswell

Comment: I just realized the code is missing a ). My bad. Its edited again

Comment: Its all good man thank you for helping me out! Its saying here now though that it's not finding Movies_filtered. Im nt sure why though because my data is definitely called Movies